# Angular Material autocomplete not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, autocomplete

I'm trying to use the autocomplete directive from angular material. I have tried to implement the example from [their website](https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/#/demo/material.components.autocomplete)

But as soon as I start typing I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined`

Angular code:

```
var spApp = angular.module('helpApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'angular-edit-row', 'ui-notification', 'uiSwitch', 'ngMaterial'])

 spApp.controller('helpListCtrl', function($scope, $http, $modal, Notification) {
  function DemoCtrl ($timeout, $q) {
var self = this;

// list of `state` value/display objects
self.states        = loadAll();
self.selectedItem  = null;
self.searchText    = null;
self.querySearch   = querySearch;

// ******************************
// Internal methods
// ******************************

/**
 * Search for states... use $timeout to simulate
 * remote dataservice call.
 */
function querySearch (query) {
  var results = query ? self.states.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : [];
  return results;
}

/**
 * Build `states` list of key/value pairs
 */
function loadAll() {
  var allStates = 'North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,Wisconsin, Wyoming';

  return allStates.split(/, +/g).map( function (state) {
    return {
      value: state.toLowerCase(),
      display: state
    };
  });
}

/**
 * Create filter function for a query string
 */
function createFilterFor(query) {
  var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);

  return function filterFn(state) {
    return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
  };

}
}

<md-autocomplete flex="" required="" md-input-name="autocompleteField" md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache" md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem" md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)" md-item-text="item.display" md-floating-label="Favorite state">
```

Code inside HTML:

```
<md-item-template>
            <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText">{{item.display}}</span>
          </md-item-template>
          <div ng-messages="searchForm.autocompleteField.$error" ng-if="searchForm.autocompleteField.$touched">
            <div ng-message="required">You <b>must</b> have a favorite state.</div>
            <div ng-message="minlength">Your entry is not long enough.</div>
            <div ng-message="maxlength">Your entry is too long.</div>
          </div>
</md-autocomplete>
```

**Edit:**
Console output:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
at L (angular-material.min.js:10)
at F (angular-material.min.js:10)
at Object.C [as fn] (angular-material.min.js:10)
at n.$get.n.$digest (angular.js:14308)
at n.$get.n.$apply (angular.js:14571)
at eg.$$debounceViewValueCommit (angular.js:23391)
at eg.$setViewValue (angular.js:23363)
at HTMLInputElement.l (angular.js:19784)
at HTMLInputElement.b.event.dispatch (jquery-1.9.1.js:973)
at HTMLInputElement.b.event.add.v.handle (jquery-1.9.1.js:913)
```

I'm sorry I cant provide a plunkr but this is production code.

Any suggestions to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: There is no `success` in any of your code. Can you try and pinpoint the error (Should be located on the right of that line in the console), and try attempt to show the codeblock where `success` is located. A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would also help tremendously if you can reproduce the issue there.

Comment: I have added console output to original post. It points to angular.js. I use `succes` in the same controller, but outside the autocomplete function. The code resides inside Sharepoint so I cant really replicate the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your controller is defined with an alias, just like the original sample:

```
ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl"
```

in your case

```
ng-controller="helpListCtrl as ctrl"
```

Answer (score 0):

`querySearch` should return a promise.

so, something like

```
function querySearch(query){
  var d = $q.defer();
  var results = query ? self.states.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : [];
  d.resolve(results)
  return d.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        angular
           .module('firstApplication', ['ngMaterial'])
           .controller('autoCompleteController', autoCompleteController);

        function autoCompleteController ($timeout, $q, $log) {
           var self = this;
           self.simulateQuery = false;
           self.isDisabled    = false;
           // list of states to be displayed
           self.states        = loadStates();
           self.querySearch   = querySearch;
           self.selectedItemChange = selectedItemChange;
           self.searchTextChange   = searchTextChange;
           self.newState = newState;
           function newState(state) {
              alert("This functionality is yet to be implemented!");
           }
           function querySearch (query) {
              var results = query ? self.states.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : self.states, deferred;
              if (self.simulateQuery) {
                 deferred = $q.defer();
                 $timeout(function () {
                       deferred.resolve( results );
                    },
              Math.random() * 1000, false);
                 return deferred.promise;
              } else {
                 return results;
              }
           }
           function searchTextChange(text) {
              $log.info('Text changed to ' + text);
           }
           function selectedItemChange(item) {
              $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));
           }
           //build list of states as map of key-value pairs
           function loadStates() {
              var allStates = 'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware,\
                 Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,\
                 Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana,\
                 Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina,\
                 North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,\
                 South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,\
                 Wisconsin, Wyoming';
              return allStates.split(/, +/g).map( function (state) {
                 return {
                    value: state.toLowerCase(),
                    display: state
                 };
              });
           }
           //filter function for search query
           function createFilterFor(query) {
              var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);
              return function filterFn(state) {
                 return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
              };
           }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="firstApplication" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="autoCompleteController as ctrl" layout="column" ng-cloak>
        <md-content class="md-padding">
            <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">
                <p><code>md-autocomplete</code> can be used to provide search results from local or remote data sources.</p>
                <md-autocomplete ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled"
                                 md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache"
                                 md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
                                 md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)"
                                 md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
                                 md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)"
                                 md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
                                 md-item-text="item.display"
                                 md-min-length="0"
                                 placeholder="US State?">
                    <md-item-template>
                        <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>
                    </md-item-template>
                    <md-not-found>
                        No states matching "{{ctrl.searchText}}" were found.
                        <a ng-click="ctrl.newState(ctrl.searchText)">Create a new one!</a>
                    </md-not-found>
                </md-autocomplete>
                <br />
                <md-checkbox ng-model="ctrl.simulateQuery">Show progress for results?</md-checkbox>
                <md-checkbox ng-model="ctrl.noCache">Disable caching?</md-checkbox>
                <md-checkbox ng-model="ctrl.isDisabled">Disable?</md-checkbox>
                <p><code>md-autocomplete</code> caches results when performing a query.  After first call, it uses the cached results to eliminate unnecessary server requests or lookup logic and it can be disabled.</p>
            </form>
        </md-content>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```